# Why does ? not work in the LIMIT for Zend_Db

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have the following:

```
public function getAll($limit = 100)
{   
    //if ($thread != 0) { $threadq = "WHERE threadId=$threadId"; }

    $query = <<<EOF
    SELECT 
        x.*
    FROM x

    ORDER BY dater DESC
    LIMIT ?
EOF;
    return self::$db->fetchAll($query, $limit);
}
```

It seems it turns the `LIMIT x` into `LIMIT 'x'` and so the MySQL query parser goes wrong and complains.

However doing `LIMIT $limit` works fine

Why does this not work? and is there another method of doing this?

Comment: No comments for the minus vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go crazy and suggest you keep it easy and use [Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html). This appears to be a simple query.

This demonstration uses a default [ZF DbTable](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.defining) as the the adapter (I could just as easily use `Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();`), however it can be adapted to almost any type of query:

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'user';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

public function getAll($limit = 100)
{
    $select = $this->select();//This is the adapter for this table and implies SELECT * FROM user 
    $select->order('name', 'DESC') //can also pass an array of columns
           ->limit($limit);//limit has a second arg for offset

    return $this->fetchAll($select);//returns a rowset object, if an array is required append ->toArray to the fetchall().
}   
}
```

Comment: Where would you create this? Would it be `Application_Model_DbTable_User` `application/model/dbtable/User.php`, And how would you call it in your controller?

Answer (score 4):

The replacement parameters must be inside array even if only single:

```
return self::$db->fetchAll($query, array($limit));
```

And for limit part of query you don't need to use ? replacement wildcard!

Comment: Wow, I totally overlooked that when commenting above. Nice catch! +1